# addChild not working in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm developing a game similar to: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/impossible-rush-hd/id964396464?mt=8

An array of ball objects ( Ball: SKNode ) with different colors is created. And every time ball touches the wheel I'm removing the ball using:

```
ball.removeFromParent()
```

This is working fine but after that I pick another random ball to display from the array and add to the scene it doesn't work. Node count shows 1 which is the Wheel node.

I call this function initially and it works fine but doesn't work the next time when called from the didBeginContact method.

```
func sendBall(){
     var randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.ballsArray.count)))
     ball = self.ballsArray[randomIndex]
     addChild(ball) //This statement has no effect when its called second time.
}
```

I'm stuck here. Can someone please help me.

Comment: Does your `Ball` class have an attached SKSpriteNode in order to provide a visual representation?

Comment: Yes, Ball class has: _var sprite: SKSpriteNode!_ to hold the color ball image.

Comment: Ok, where do you set the position of the Balls? Is it possible that they are spawning off screen?

Comment: I set the position of ball when I initialize them _ball.position = CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.center.y + ball.sprite.size.height * 5_ and then add it to array. I can see two nodes initially ( wheel & ball ) after I removeFromParent I see only one node count. So addChild(ball) doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but doesn't work the next time when called from the didBeginContact
>   method.

We can't add child inside the didBeginContact, 
do it from didSimulatePhysics method

Set a flag in didBeginContact() and in didSimulatePhysics() check flag and call sendBall() and reset the flag :)